# How to configure vsdiffmerge tool as external diff/merge tool in TortoiseGit?

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tortoisegit

I tried setting a for external diff tool in TortoiseGit settings for diff:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\vsDiffMerge.exe %mine %base
```

but no use, also need command for merge

Answer (score 0):

For Diff use:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\vsDiffMerge.exe" %base %mine /t
```

For Merge use:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\vsDiffMerge.exe" /m /t %mine %theirs %base %merged
```

The TortoiseGit manual for configuring diff and merge tools can be found here: https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-progs

Comment: For newer VS, the tool can be found in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\20nn\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\vsDiffMerge.exe"

Comment: nope not working, i can see some application is about to open on taskbar but gets closed as soon as I trigger diff/merge from tortoiseGit

Comment: It's working for me on Win7 x64 with VS2017 Community

Comment: Maybe you have to remove the `/t`.